# How to show persitent message on android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have searched how to show a persistent message on android screen like Cerberus application does but I can't find. If any one has an idea?

Persistent message mean message keep visible on screen even you switch application or even you lock the phone? [Image of screen message](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1u3LzJ7PAhWRuB4KHVOhCx0QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.com%2Fcerberus-your-phone-s-guardian-dog&psig=AFQjCNF48ekpJvKiPf-WDD5I-QUAFyIzUA&ust=1474482947649250)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW probably

Answer (score 0):

You can disabled home key, back key and whatever key that you wants preventing closing your app with this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent){
  return true;
}
```

Remember launch this block screen when your smartphone turned on with boot complete broadcast receiver.

Comment: Android don't allow block key and i want my message keep showing even the using use an another app.